# When i click on my html button it just gives me php code?

Tags: php, html

As the title says my PHP code is running normally when I execute it alone ( it just gives me connection suu! and nothing else) but when activate it with HTML submit input it just shows my PHP code on a page.

this is my HTML button code cut from a much bigger and correct code:

```
<form action="read.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="read" class="btn btn-secondary py-3 px-4">
</form>
```

and this is the PHP:

```
<?php
require 'connec.php';

try {

 
    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM appointments');
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      $e->getMessage();
      
    }
    foreach ($result as $row) {
      echo $row['Date'] . ' ' . $row['Heure'] . ' ' . $row['Duree'];
      
    }
```

and as you can see when I click 'read' it just turns my entire site page into the PHP code.
How can I at least make it give me "connection succ!" ?????

Comment: Are you running the HTML page via web server? Apache, Nginx or directly?

Comment: Make sure 1) you're using a webserver and accessing the files via `http://localhost` (e.g. http://localhost/yourscriptfile.php`) and not via `file://`, 2) that webserver has PHP installed in it, and 3) your file is named with a `.php` extension.

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing at the likely problem here:

You're trying to develop/learn on your own personal computer.
While you can develop and run HTML (and JavaScript) on your personal computer, you cannot run PHP on your local computer without installing and configuring additional libraries.  XAMPP is a common, and good, choice for installing the additional components you need:  https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

To clarify, in order to run a .php script on any computer, PHP needs to be installed on that computer, and server software needs to be running in order to run that and send it to your browser.

Since your computer is not a publicly-accessible server, what you develop will not be usable (available on the internet).  So, the next step, after you get your site working on your personal computer, will be to move your work to a server.  The most most common, and easiest way, to do this is to getting a web hosting subscription from one of the many many web hosting services that are available out there.  There, PHP will already be installed and configured.  Because of that, depending on your preference, you could also just do your work on the web hosting server (rather than having the files on your local personal computer).  But, as ADyson has pointed out in the discussion here, there are good reasons to keep your development work on your personal computer.  Though, you're really going to want to learn version control (git) if you do it that way, and still want to publish your work on a public server.

Comment: If you are developing on you local computer, you could learn to use Laragon to make your computer could serve the PHP file.

Comment: `php -S localhost:8000 -t .` can be used to serve the entire project folder

Comment: `However, doing so would be somewhat unusual.`....not if you're a developer. Then it would be a very normal thing to do

Comment: `you'll want to go ahead and start putting your work on a server`...not until you've tested it and checked its working and secure. Local testing is generally used to achieve this. VMs and containerisation are also potential options to create a clean development environment which mirrors the target one. Suggesting that the OP does their development on their public server is, quite frankly,  terrible advice.

Comment: Know your audience here.  This is clearly someone just starting out.  While you are perfectly correct about VM's and containers being an option, offering five different options that are way beyond them, at this point, is not helpful.  You may know a lot about the subject matter, but you might also want to look into pedagogy a bit.  The answer I provided 1) addresses the conceptual issue at hand & 2) directs the person down the most helpful path.   ......Beding pedantic is not helpful.

Comment: @AdamWinter I'm not trying to be pedantic. A VM or container might be a tad more advanced - but turnkey solutions exist for both...I'm not proposing the OP builds their own. The idea is to get a ready-made environment which they don't have to know how to configure. Equally, installing something like XAMPP or Laragon provides the same, and is the work of a few minutes and simple clicks. Installing a software package should not be an intimidating task for anyone who aspires to learn to write computer programs. But it does make it super-easy to set up a local dev environment with no fuss.

Comment: Whereas developing directly on a live server has distinct disadvantages: 1) It's more time-consuming and fiddly as you either have to edit the code files in a web-based editor, potentially with no syntax highlighting to help (and no code completion), or you have to keep SFTP-ing them back and forth from the local machine, to run them. 2) It's also hard/impossible to use a debugger. 3) It's a lot harder to use source control. 4) You have no controlled, live copy of the system, you're just building it as you go along. Anything you get wrong or do insecurely is immediately public.

Comment: 5) Most things a beginner would be likely to do for learning purposes are unlikely to be of much interest to anyone else anyway. 6) It goes against all establishes sane practice, and no-one should be leading a new coder down the road of bad habits...they're often hard to ditch (because once they're up and running, many people dislike new learning curves and will avoid them, and keep doing things they way they know, for fear of breaking things or being slowed down). 7) They have to pay for a server they don't really need, or subsist on a crummy free ad-serving plan which goes down half the time

Comment: In summary...the tools exist to make developing locally very easy, almost at the touch of a button to get a usable environment. And then it makes lots of other tools (IDE, source control, debuggers, ease of testing, etc etc etc) which a new dev will gradually need to get to grips with, available far more easily than if they were trying to code remotely on a bog-standard hosting platform. I get that you may disagree, but for me it's a no-brainer, hence these comments.

Comment: You make good points.  I guess it's a question of which one you should spend your time learning first.  All of those things you've said are true, but they don't mean anything if you end up quickly writing a perfect site, but don't have any clue how to make it an actual site that people can see & user.

Comment: That's certainly true. But that's again something you can learn without too much trouble, and will be covered in tutorials, books etc. And in the case of PHP site, moving it to the hosting server is generally just a case of copying the files and changing the database login.

Comment: I've edited my answer here.  I will point out that one of the main benefits of developing remotely (on a development server) is that you can do it from anywhere.  I can have three different computers I work from, and they only need the IDE installed, not AMP.  Also, your IDE will totally do linting, syntax highlighting, code completion, and auto SFTP-uploading over a remote connection.  Only your point about debuggers is not trivial.   Also, I disagree with your point about source control.  It's the IDE that makes it "easier" not the local environment.  They should learn command line anyway.